# Delete Associated Workflows after document has been deleted

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share

on delete of a document, by default the workflow is left in a hanging state and the reference of the document gets removed from the workflow side (bpm_package).

I want to change it as follows: if a document has been deleted in the repository then all the workflow that are associated with it should get deleted (each workflow package will always have a single document)

I tried to implement this by using rule/action (items are deleted or leave this folder) - was able to find workflows in js and cancel them, but it does not delete the document nor the workflow. on checking the XHR request i was able to find out that a `concurrency exception` occurs between the action and onDelete policy.

how do i delete/cancel/close the associated workflows of a document

i'm using alfresco community 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create Behavior/Policie to achieve this task.

http://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/references/dev-extension-points-behaviors.html

You can use beforeDeleteNode/onDeleteNode behaviour and write logic here to delete workflow.

Comment: You have to combine both method in that policy.

beforeDeleteNode()  will give the noderef and assign it as global variable use that noderef in  onDeleteNode()  method to delete that noderef.